# notifyDataSetChanged() not working for my listView

Tags: listview, kotlin

I am in need of some help. I have been trying to implement a SearchView, but when I use a filter the data not change.

My project contains a listview with an adapter.

Why doesn't my ListView show the new data when I call notifyDataSetChanged?

Let me know if you need specific pieces of code or for more information. 
Please help me. thanks in advance

```
class FragmentDiagnosticsTableViewController : Fragment(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

lateinit var mSwipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
lateinit var elementList: ListView
lateinit var elementListAdapter: ElementAdapter

override fun onRefresh() {

    try {

        if (connected) {

            MaintenanceTableViewController().diagnosticSend()
            while (!csvOkey) {

            }
            saveFile()

            elementListAdapter = ElementAdapter(context!!, totalDiagnosticEntries)

            elementList.adapter = elementListAdapter

            csvOkey = false

        } else {

            try {

                DiagnosticsTableViewController().loadFileCsv(mContext)
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)
                elementListAdapter = ElementAdapter(context!!, totalDiagnosticEntries)
                elementList.adapter = elementListAdapter

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Impossible to refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)

            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {

        Toast.makeText(activity, "Impossible to refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)

    }
}


companion object {

    fun newInstance(): Fragment {
        var fb: FragmentDiagnosticsTableViewController = FragmentDiagnosticsTableViewController()
        return fb
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val rootView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diagnostic, container,
            false)

    var builder = StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())

    mContext = activity as MaintenanceTableViewController
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipeRefresh)
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this)
    elementList = rootView.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.elementList)


    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Diagnostics"
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    return rootView

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.men_search, menu)

    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search View Hint")



    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {


        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            //Task HERE
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                elementListAdapter.filter("")
                elementList.clearTextFilter()


            } else {
                elementListAdapter.filter(newText)

            }

            return true
        }


    })

}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    try {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.shareButton) {
            var intentShareFile = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            val fileWithinMyDir = filePathMessageLogger
            try {
                if (fileWithinMyDir != null) {
                    if (fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
                        intentShareFile.setType("text/plain")
                        val fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity!!, "com.example.saradalmonte.pocketserviceandroid", fileWithinMyDir!!)
                        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURI)
                        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "File Csv")
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share file"))
                        return true
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error File not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error File not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }


    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error File not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return true
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    if (view != null) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        elementListAdapter = ElementAdapter(context!!, totalDiagnosticEntries)
        elementList.adapter = elementListAdapter

    }
}

fun saveFile() {
    val ma = activity as MaintenanceTableViewController
    ma.saveFileDiagnostic()
}

class ElementAdapter : BaseAdapter {

    var totalDiagnosticEntries = mutableListOf<DiagnosticsEntry>()
    var filteredDiagnosticsEntry = arrayListOf<DiagnosticsEntry>()
    var mcontext: Context? = null
    lateinit var inflater: LayoutInflater


    constructor(context: Context, totalDiagnosticEntries: MutableList<DiagnosticsEntry>) : super() {
        this.totalDiagnosticEntries = totalDiagnosticEntries
        this.mcontext = context
    }

    fun listViewAdapter(context: Context, totalDiagnosticEntries: MutableList<DiagnosticsEntry>) {

        mcontext = context
        this.totalDiagnosticEntries = totalDiagnosticEntries
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        this.filteredDiagnosticsEntry.addAll(totalDiagnosticEntries)

    }


    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return totalDiagnosticEntries[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return totalDiagnosticEntries.size
    }


    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {

        val element = totalDiagnosticEntries[p0]
        var inflator = mcontext!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var myView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.element_diagnostic, null)

        myView.text_No.text = element.No!!
        myView.text_TimeStamp.text = element.Timestamp!!
        myView.text_errorCode.text = element.Code!!

        if (element.Message1 == "") {
            myView.text_Message1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            myView.text_Message1.visibility = (View.VISIBLE)
            myView.text_Message1.text = element.Message1!!
        }
        if (element.Message2 == "") {

            myView.text_Message2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        } else {
            myView.text_Message2.visibility = (View.VISIBLE)
            myView.text_Message2.text = element.Message2!!
        }

        val type = element.Type

        if (type == "8002") {

            val colorBar = myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.color_bar)
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(mcontext!!, R.color.greenSE)
            colorBar.setBackgroundColor(color)
        } else if (type == "2") {
            val colorBar = myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.color_bar)
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(mcontext!!, R.color.Yellow)
            colorBar.setBackgroundColor(color)

        } else if (type == "3") {
            val colorBar = myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.color_bar)
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(mcontext!!, R.color.Orange)
            colorBar.setBackgroundColor(color)

        } else if (type == "4") {
            val colorBar = myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.color_bar)
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(mcontext!!, R.color.Red)
            colorBar.setBackgroundColor(color)
        } else {
            val colorBar = myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.color_bar)
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(mcontext!!, R.color.Grey)
            colorBar.setBackgroundColor(color)
        }

        myView.color_bar.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(mcontext!!, DiagnosticsEntryDetailTableViewCell::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("text_No", element.No)
            intent.putExtra("text_TimeStamp", element.Timestamp)
            intent.putExtra("text_Type", element.Type)
            intent.putExtra("text_Object", element.Object)
            intent.putExtra("text_Istance", element.Instance)

            intent.putExtra("text_Object", element.Object)
            intent.putExtra("text_Code", element.Code)
            intent.putExtra("text_Message1", element.Message1)
            intent.putExtra("text_Message2", element.Message2)
            mContext!!.startActivity(intent)
        }
        return myView
    }

    fun filter(charText: String) {

        var charText = charText
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
        filteredDiagnosticsEntry.clear()
        if (charText.length == 0) {
            filteredDiagnosticsEntry.addAll(totalDiagnosticEntries)
        } else {
            for (wp: DiagnosticsEntry in totalDiagnosticEntries) {
                if (wp.No!!.contains(charText) || wp.Object!!.contains(charText) || wp.Instance!!.contains(charText) || wp.Message1!!.contains(charText)
                        || wp.Message2!!.contains(charText)) {


                    filteredDiagnosticsEntry.add(wp)
                }
            }
        }

        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You filter diagnostics entries and put them into `filteredDiagnosticsEntry`, but in adapter in method `getView(...)` you still use `totalDiagnosticEntries`.

Try to replace accordingly `totalDiagnosticEntries` with `filteredDiagnosticsEntry` in methods `getItem()`, `getCount()`, `getView()` and maybe in other fragment of your code. Please check documentation for BaseAdapter.

For example:

> **getCount()**
>
> How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.

It means, how many elements you want to display on ListView by this Adapter. If you provide size of `totalDiagnosticEntries`, the Adapter will try to display as many items as `totalDiagnosticEntries` contains - calling `getView` for each of them.